# Creating StackedColumn100 in C# Chart

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, charts

I'm trying to create a StackedColumn100 in a C# Chart to replicate one I have in Excel:
[image: Chart Image]

I pull the data from SQL Server and step through it like so:

```cs
BarChart.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
BarChart.Series.Clear();

foreach (DataRow row in BarChart.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string name = row[0].ToString();

    BarChart.Series.Add(new Series(name));
    BarChart.Series[name].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn100;

    BarChart.Series[name].Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, row[2].ToString()));
    BarChart.Series[name].Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, row[1].ToString()));
}
```

How this just produces something like this:
[image: Incorrect chart]

I've tried multiple different ways, but all seem to produce something similar to the second image. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Well the range of x-values seems to be a tad limited, don't you think?

Comment: Also: You probably want only 2 Series! And finally try to add the y-values as numbers!